# When will Android 2.2 be ready for HTC Wildfire with Sense (from Germany)

Tags: htc-sense, 2.2-froyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get Android 2.2 (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-android-2-2-froyo)

I am using an HTC Wildfire on the Rogers Canada network, and I purchased the phone on eBay from Germany. HTC tech support informed me that when Germany releases the 2.2 update it will be available over the air for my phone.

Does anyone have an idea when we can expect this update to be available? Will there be any issues with Sense and my installed applications and data when I apply the update?

Thanks!